# Add a custom word to a cross reference in LaTex

Tags: cross-referencing

I've been searching for a time but I can't reach a solution to my problem. I'm writing my master thesis, and I want to add custom words to my references, I mean, if I want to ref the only table in my document (`\label{table:test`} for example), I usually do `\ref{table:test}`, getting as a result just a clickable number 1.

However, I need to set a global option in order to, always I refer to a table, for example, I get `{custom word} 1`(1 for the first table). This custom word surely will be `Table`, but I can desire to use `Figure`(in English) or `Imagen` (in spanish), for ref figures.

What do I need in my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the cleveref package, it provides the `\cref{table:test}` command and you can define your custom names in singular and plural using, for example, `\Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I know about cleverer package but yours is a local solution if I'm not wrong. I'm trying to do something like: `\newcommand\figureref[1]{%\hyperref[#1]{\crefname*{Custom word}{#1}}}`but doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Same solution that in the answer of user33593 but with a MWE:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\renewcommand\tablename{Foo}
\crefname{table}{foo}{foos}
\begin{document}
See \cref{foo}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering\fbox{An example foo}
\caption{foo\label{foo}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And with `fncylab` instead of `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fncylab}
\labelformat{table}{foo #1}
\renewcommand\tablename{Foo}
\begin{document}
See \ref{foo} 
\begin{table}[h]
\centering\fbox{An example foo}
\caption{foo\label{foo}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```